# TDD - writing tests for a method that iterates / works with collections

Tags: c#, collections, tdd

As a newcomer to TDD I'm stuggling with writing unit tests that deal with collections.  For example at the moment I'm trying to come up with some test scearios to essentially test the following method

```
int Find(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate);
```

Where the method should return the index of the first item in the list `list` that matches the predicate `predicate`.  So far the only test cases that I've been able to come up with have been along the lines of

- When `list` contains no items - returns `-1`
- When `list` contains 1 item that matches `predicate` - returns `0`
- When `list` contains 1 item that doesn't match `predicate` - returns `-1`
- When `list` contains 2 items both of which match `predicate` - return `0`
- When `list` contains 2 items, the first of which match `predicate` - return `0`
- etc...

As you can see however these test cases are both numerous and don't satisfactorily test the actual behaviour that I actually want.  The mathematician in me wants to do some sort of TDD-by-induction

- When `list` contains no items - returns `-1`
- When `list` contains N items call `predicate` on the first item and then recursively call `Find` on the remaining N-1 items

However this introduces unneccessary recursion.  What sort of test cases should I be looking to write in TDD for the above method?

---

As an aside the method that I am trying to test really is just `Find`, simply for a specific collection and predicate (which I can independently write test cases for).  Surely there should be a way for me to avoid having to write any of the above test cases and instead simply test that the method calls some other `Find` implementation (e.g. [`FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx)) with the correct arguments?

Note that in any case I'd still like to know *how* I could unit test `Find` (or another method like it) even if it turns out that in this case I don't need to.

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: @Kevin Rhino mocks + MSTest / the Visual Studio unit testing framework

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If find() is working, then it should return the index of the first element that matches the predicate, right?

So you'll need a test for the empty list case, and one for the no-matching elements case, and one for a matching element case.  I would find that sufficient.  In the course of TDDing find() I might write a special first-element-passes case, which I could fake easily.  I would probably write:

```
emptyListReturnsMinusOne()
singlePassingElementReturnsZero()
noPassingElementsReturnsMinusOne()
PassingElementMidlistReturnsItsIndex()
```

And expect that sequence would drive my correct implementation.

Comment: You might want to add a `PassingElementAtEndOfListReturnsItsIndex()` test.

Comment: It's hard for me to envision a realistic solution that would pass the midlist test but fail the endOfList test.

Comment: I could imagine the situation where someone decides a for loop would be faster than a foreach and introduces an off by one error. That person would be an idiot of course, but personally I write my tests for idiots (usually me being the idiot as it turns out :) )

Comment: Actually after five minutes thought the single instance case would catch this but I still think testing all boundary cases is useful.

Answer (score 2):

> Stop testing when fear is replaced by boredom - Kent Beck

In this case, what is the probability that given a passing test for

- "When list contains 2 items both of which match predicate - return 0"

the following test will fail ?

- "When list contains 5 items both of which match predicate - return 0"

I'd write the former because I'm afraid that the behavior doesn't work for multiple elements. However once 2 works, writing another one for 5 is just tedium (Unless there is a hardcoded assumption of 2 in the production code.. which should have been refactored away. Even if it is not, I'd just modify the existing test to have 5 instead of 2 and make it work for the general case).

So write tests for significantly different things. In this case, list with (zero, one, many) elements and (contains/does not contain) operand

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement for `Find` method, here's what I would test:

1. `list` is `null` - throws `ArgumentNullException` or returns `-1`
2. `list` contains no items - returns `-1`
3. `predicate` is `null` - throws `ArgumentNullException` or returns `-1`
4. `list` contains one item that doesn't match the `predicate` - returns `-1`
5. `list` contains one item that matches the `predicate` - returns `0`
6. `list` contains multiple items, but no item matches the `predicate` - returns `-1`
7. `list` contains multiple items that match the `predicate` - returns index of first match

Basically, you would first test for end cases - null arguments, empty list. After that, one item tests. Finally, test match and non-match for multiple items.

For `null` arguments, you could either throw exception, or return `-1`, depending on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the **list**, change the **predicates**.

Think about how the method will be called.  When someone is calling the `Find` method they will already have a list and need to think of predicates.  So think of good examples that demonstrate the behavior of `Find`:

**Example:**
Using same list `3, 4` for all testcases makes it easy to understand:

1. Predicate `< 5` matches both numbers (returns `1`)
2. Predicate `== 3` matches `3` (returns `0`)
3. Predicate `== 0` matches none (returns `-1`)

This is really all you need to specify the behavior and by changing the predicates rather than the list you give good examples of how to use the `Find` method.  A list with zero, one, or two elements isn't really changing the behavior of `Find` and not really how the method will be used.  Follow DRY with your testcases, focus on specifying behavior not proving code is correct or you will end up spending all your time writing tests.

Answer (score 0):

To try to answer your aside: I don't have any experience with Rhino mocks, but I believe it should have something similar to FakeItEasy(?):

```
var finder = A.Fake<IMyFindInterface>();

// ... insert code to call IMyFindInterface.Find(whatever) here

A.CallTo(() => finder.find(A<List>.That.Matches(
                  x => x.someProperty == someValue))).MustHaveHappened();
```

By putting the implementation of Find() behind an interface, and then passing the method that would uses that interface a fake, you can check that the method is called with certain parameters. (The *MustHaveHappended()* will cause the test to fail if the expected call is not completed).

Since you know that the real implementation of *IMyFindInterface* just passes the call on to an implementation you already trust, this should be a good enough test to verify that the code you are testing calls the Find-implementation in the correct way.

This same procedure can be used whenever you just want to ensure that your code (the unit  you are testing) calls some component you already trust in a correct way by abstracting away that component itself - exactly what we want when unit-testing.